# GSAP: Overriding and replacing animation between states on Click/Keydown Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

http://allthetime.co.nf/GSAPslider/

I'm developing a GSAP slider and it works well now with keyboard and click control. I want to be able to animate between states upon receiving a click/key event. So, when it's on slide 1 and I click the button for slide 4 instead of going to slide 4 instantly, the animation scrolls quickly across slide 2 and 3 and then lands at 4.

Any ideas?

Comment: Set up your slides so instead of animating each one individually, animate an enclosing div to the required positions.

Comment: That makes way more sense. Thanks.